# Como enviar un objeto que contiene claves dinamicas - TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Estoy trabajando sobre un objeto en `TypeScript` que puede venir con claves dinámicas desde mi endpoint, cada clave devuelve un arreglo. Esta es la estructura del objeto que recibo del endpoint:

```
    "todosModelos": {
    "dimension": [
        "23"
    ],
    "color": [
        "Verde",
        "Negro"
    ]
},
```

Y todosModelos tiene el siguiente tipado:

```
export interface todosModelos {
  
  [key: string]: string[];
}
```

Y las posibles claves estan en un arreglo de objetos que es el siguiente:

```
    const todosTiposClaves = [{
    name: 'Color',
    code: 'color'
  },
  {
    name: 'Dimesión',
    code: 'dimension'
  },
  {
    name: 'Calidad',
    code: 'calidad'
  },
  {
    name: 'Durabilidad',
    code: 'durabilidad'
  }];
```

Con todo esto obtengo un arreglo para llenar un componente RadioButton en React. Y a la hora de seleccionar y enviar al endpoint de adicionar nuevo modelo tengo que verificar que si existe algún radioButton que tenga un valor `no-select` y no enviarlo. Me cree la siguiente funcionalidad para validar que no existe algo con valor `no-select` y es la funcion que pongo a continuación:

```
const submitNewVariation = () => {
    
    const value_of_post = getValues();
    
    const data_send = {
      attributes: value_of_post,
    }
    
    allAttributes.map((item) => {
  
      if (value_of_post.hasOwnProperty(item.code)) {

        if(value_of_post[item.code] === 'no_select'){
          
          delete value_of_post[item.code]
        } 
      }
    });

    if(Object.entries(data_send.attributes).length >= 2){
      
      //addVariationProduct(product, data_send, modal);
    } else {
      toast.error('Debe seleccionar al menos dos opciones para registrar la variación');
    } 
  }
```

Pero cuando envio recibo un error 401 del endpint como respuesta y me saca de la aplicacion. Algun detalle en mi codigo que quizas no estoy teniendo en cuenta? El endpoint recibe la informacion asi:

```
"modelos": {
        "color": "23",
        "size": "XL",
        "material": "buena"
    },
```

Comment: El error 401 te dices que tienes problemas de autenticación